# RStudio not detecting installed R

Tags: r, installation, rstudio

I have R installed on my system, but R studio does not appear to recognise it. Please advise on how I should proceed.

This is the error:

> R doesn't seem to be installed. Before using R studio, please install R.

Comment: What operating system? What versions of OS, R, RStudio? How did you install R? Can you run R manually? If so, how are you doing that?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Pro, 64bit, core i5. I am using RStudio-2021.  RTools (64-bit: rtools40v2-x86_64.exe ). https://cran.r-project.org/ (The one specified for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to fix the problem. I uninstalled the one I downloaded early and installed the base version